# Control allowed drop locations for jQuery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list where the user can dynamically attach items to each other. In the following example "Item 3" is attached to "Item 2". If two items are attached I want to prevent the user from dropping items between the two items ie in the example the user should not be allowed to drop an item between "Item 2" and "Item 3".

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li class="attached">Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a callback which allows me to control which drop locations are allowed? Alternatively is there a different plugin similar to jQuery sortable which can provide this functionality?

Comment: I don't really understand what is happening here I am afraid - quite lost indeed. Perhaps you can make a jsFiddle to help us understand what you mean by "dynamically attach items to each other"?

Comment: @derfred In this example you have item 3 as attached, to item two is it always attached to item above it and not below it also if it is attached to item two what should happens if you sort item two should I'm three got with it ?

Comment: Valid points @mcgrailm. If you don't want to sort both item 2 & 3, then, you can freeze them. [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/items.html)

Comment: sorry for the typos @derfred In this example you have item 3 as attached to item 2. Is an attached item always attached to the item above it and not below it ? Also,if it is attached to item two what should happen if you sort item 2 should Item three go with it ?

Comment: @mcgrailm, yes that's exactly the behaviour I would like to acheive. In the meantime I've settled for hiding the handle on item 2 such that both item 2 & 3 are frozen.

Comment: sounds to me like what you really want is a nested  sortable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery sortable widget does not provide the capability for controlling the allowed drop zone behaviour. The problem can however be solved hackish-ly by subclassing the the widget:

```
$.widget("ui.custom_list", $.ui.sortable, {
  _mouseDrag: function(event) {
    // copy this code from the source code of jquery.ui.sortable.js

    //Rearrange
    for (var i = this.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

      //Cache variables and intersection, continue if no intersection
      var item = this.items[i], itemElement = item.item[0], intersection = this._intersectsWithPointer(item);
      if (!intersection) continue;

      if(itemElement != this.currentItem[0] //cannot intersect with itself
        &&  this.placeholder[intersection == 1 ? "next" : "prev"]()[0] != itemElement //no useless actions that have been done before
        &&  !$.ui.contains(this.placeholder[0], itemElement) //no action if the item moved is the parent of the item checked
        && (this.options.type == 'semi-dynamic' ? !$.ui.contains(this.element[0], itemElement) : true)


        // add this line
        && this._allowDropping(itemElement, (intersection == 1 ? "down" : "up"))



        //&& itemElement.parentNode == this.placeholder[0].parentNode // only rearrange items within the same container
      ) {

        this.direction = intersection == 1 ? "down" : "up";

      // Rest of the function

  },

  _allowDropping: function(itemElement, direction) {
    if(this.options.allowDropping) {
      return this.options.allowDropping(itemElement, direction);
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

The _mouseDrag function is mostly copied from the sortable source. The only adjustment is the line:

```
&& this._allowDropping(itemElement, (intersection == 1 ? "down" : "up"))
```

The allowed drop zone behaviour can then be customized by providing a function for the allowDropping parameter:

```
$("ul").custom_list({
  allowDropping: function(element, direction) {
    // element refers to the item that would be moved but not the one being dragged
    if(direction == "up") {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: could you please add `jsfiddle` with complete code? in your code, at one place, you wrote `// Rest of the function` because of which, I am assuming that this code incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You can optionally pass sortable an [`items`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-items) option which lets you specify which items you want to be sortable. Note that with this method you will not be able to move items two and three around.

**Html**

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li class="attached">Item 2</li>
  <li class="attached">Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#sortable").sortable({ items: ':not(.attached)'});
```

Hope that gets you on the right track. Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SPPVc/

Comment: Wow, thanks for the demo. There's just one problem with the behaviour: if the frozen items (ie. element with class attached) drop to the bottom of the list, one cannot drop an element at the end of the list.

Comment: For example in the following demo, try moving item 2 to the end of the list http://jsfiddle.net/derfred/bGJTR/

Comment: @derfred: Agreed--I'll take a look.